# How can I get a name of the image having its id?

Tags: android, android-resources

I have an array of int. Those integers are the resource id's for the pictures:

```
final int flags[] = new int[] { R.drawable.argentina, R.drawable.austria ... }
```

and a String that holds the name of the image resource:

```
String flag = "R.drawable.argentina";
```

How can I easy check whether flag String is in flags array or not?

When I retrieve a value from the array and assign it the variable for example:

```
int flag = flag[0];
```

This flag variable will hold some integer like 2130837665 which is obvious.
How can I retrieve exact name from this array as a String that way I can compare it to the flag String?

Comment: You can use getResources().getIdentifier() function for finding id of drawable in flag and then you can search it in your array

Comment: I try to avoid getIdentifier() since I need to pass to it the name of the image, that require additional processing to retrieve it from the String. I was hoping that there is maybe some way to do it using existing String without touching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the name of the resource by using

```
   String name = getResources().getResourceEntryName(flag]);
```

This gives name only, `argentina` in your case

You can get the type by

```
String type = getResources().getResourceTypeName(flag);
```

This will return `drawable` in your case. So you can find whether the id corresponds to the string

Answer (score 1):

use this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button MyTranslateButton;   
private int  image[];   
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
  image =new int[]{R.drawable.adv_book,R.drawable.background,R.drawable.bid_active,R.drawable.break_finish};     


    MyTranslateButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.TranslateButton);

    MyTranslateButton.setOnClickListener(MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener);
}

private Button.OnClickListener MyTranslateButtonOnClickListener
  = new Button.OnClickListener(){
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void onClick(View v) {
     for(int i=0 ; i < image.length ; i++){     
         String names[]=new String[image.length];
         String name=getResources().getResourceEntryName(image[i]);         
        Log.i("Image Names is ",name);
        names[i]=getResources().getResourceEntryName(image[i]);

      }

}

};
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only need one method from your code: getResources().getResourceEntryName();